# html5: How do I link my form to my video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have 2 html files, I'm trying to make a basic video upload process using html5/js.

I don't know how to fetch the file and push it into the video tag in the second html document.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Front page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="video player.html">
  <input type="file"   accept="video/*">
  <input type="submit">

</form>
<script>
  console.log(userInput);
  </script>



<p><strong>Note:</strong> Butts</p>
```

Second page w/ video tags:

```
    <!doctype html>
<style>

</style>

<head>
</head>
<video src="" width="400" controls>
  <source type="file" name="vid" type="video/*">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<body>
</body>

<script>
</script>

<html>
```

I know this is very basic but I'm new to this and stuck.  I haven't coded much in a very long time and have been trying to figure it out on my own but can't seem to get the syntax right.  if I remember correctly I need to use getelementbyID somewhere?  Anyways, thanks again.

edit: typos

Comment: Are you talking about playing the file the user has chosen to upload in a `<video>` element while it uploads?  You could accomplish this with the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File), but I'm not sure if it could be done across multiple pages.

Comment: It could probably only be done through post which JavaScript cannot access.

Comment: I want the chosen file to open in the second page in the video element after it's uploaded

Comment: You can initiate file upload via html and script, but to store file you need a server-side script as PHP (which has permission to save the file).

Comment: does anybody know where I can find a good guide to do this?  I just have my mind set on it and would really appreciate any additional guideance